# Programmatically uncheck layer in AxTOCControl

Tags: arcgis-engine

I am running my map in dynamic display mode, and I want to programmatically uncheck a layer that is not a IDynamicLayer that is visible in the AxTocControl -- its just a regular layer file.

I thought that `layer.Visible = false;` with a map refresh would work, but bafflingly it does not.

I'm using ArcEngine 10 VS2010 & C#

Comment: Have you set its buddycontrol to be the map control?

Comment: There's refresh and then there's refresh; how are you refreshing the map?

Comment: @MathiasWestin yes, I set it to my AxMapControl, like this:  toolbarControl.SetBuddyControl(mapControl);

Comment: @Michael Todd mapcontrol.Refresh()

Comment: Try using `mapcontrol.Refresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGeography, null, mapcontrol.Extent);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the samples: [Layer property page and property sheet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000000v1000000.htm) you need to use [ActiveView.ContentsChanged](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ContentsChanged_Method/0012000001ms000000/) to refresh the TOC when working with layer visibility.